# Implementing C code in Python libmpsse

Tags: python, c, ftdi

I need to interface with a FT4232 from FTDI.
I have found a few library with python (pyftdi, pylibftdi, etc)
But either they do not have I2C implemented, or they only support 32 bits (such as mpsse itself from ftdi).

I have found a library (in C) which it states that it has a python wrapper.
https://code.google.com/p/libmpsse/
I tried to simply import the .py code in my code, but it gives me an error that I dont have the pylibmpsse.py file (it is imported in the beggining of the code)

I am pretty much new to python. Is there an easy way to create a wrapper for this code? does the C code needs to be compiled first?

than you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The libmpsse library compiles mpsse.i file which will generate pylibmpsse module with [swig](http://www.swig.org). You just have to compile to use this library. For example:

```
./configure && make all install
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, I will have better luck trying to do all this on a Linux machine or a VM, it seems to be a pain to install everything under windows, I got Mingw installed, but i'm having a hard time installing libmpsse witch depends on Swig and libftdi1 which depends on libusb...

Comment: If you don't require to run it inside Windows, it will be a lot easier to compile it in Linux. I've searched, but could not find any binary (compiled) version of libmpsse.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I will have to use another alternative. My actual goal is to use the ft4232H with UART, GPIO, SPI and I2C, with cross platform compatibility and work on 32 and 64 bits. I have found a bunch of libraries, such as libmpsse, pyftdi, pylibftdi, pyd2xx, pyusb (d2xx from ftdi) much most of them either doesn't seem to have I2C compatibility or they aren't cross platform...